# Add new instance of movieClip_A to position of movieClip_B

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, addchild

I am creating a farm game and I am trying to drag an object (red spot) over the ground. When the object rolls over a soil square it highlights a different color. I am trying to drop the object onto the colored soil and have it plant some corn. My cornCrop movieClip is supposed to appear in the middle of the highlighted soil. I posted some code and a screenshot. In the code snippet i have some hard-coded x,y coordinates for the corn stalk to appear. How do I get the corn stalk to dynamically appear in the center of the highlighted soil movieClip? Plus, I can see that I should probably use some sort of array for the corn because I don't know how many times a user will want to plant them. I am not sure how to do that either.

ScreenShot URL: http://sdrv.ms/193vyIm

```
if (bucketCorn.hitTestObject(Grid.Cell_3_1))
        {
            var gridID = Grid.Cell_3_1;
            //addCrop();
            //myColorTransform.color = 0x00FF33;
            //Grid.Cell_3_1.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
            trace("Yogi Bear!");
            var cropCorn1 = new CropCorn();

            cropCorn1.x = 50;
            cropCorn1.y = 400;

            addChild(cropCorn1);
        }

        if (bucketCorn.hitTestObject(Grid.Cell_3_2))
        {
            //addCrop();
            //myColorTransform.color = 0x00FF33;
            //Grid.Cell_3_2.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
            var cropCorn3 = new CropCorn();

            Grid.Cell_3_2.addChild(cropCorn3);

        }
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

For the x,y coordinates

```
cropCorn1.x = bucketCorn.x;

cropCorn1.y = bucketCorn.y;
```

or

```
cropCorn1.x = bucketCorn.x + Grid.Cell_3_1.width / 2;

cropCorn1.y = bucketCorn.y + Grid.Cell_3_1.height / 2;
```

for the array of corn

```
var cornArray:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int = 0;i<100;i++){

    cornArray.push(CropCorn());

}
```

then just use each positon of array starting at 0. so

```
cornArray[0].x = bucketCorn.x;

cornArray[0].y = bucketCorn.y;
```

and on your next event

```
cornArray[1].x = bucketCorn.x;

cornArray[1].y = bucketCorn.y;
```